# How to use Javascript to have only one aria-selected="true" and the rest "false" at a time?

Tags: javascript

I'm using an App from shopify but the developer doesn't support customization so I'm trying to do some tweaking. I have a tab that has two options which are button, when both are clicked back and forth, they stay aria-selected="true". I want only one to be true while the other is false when only one is clicked. How? Below is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
  <div role="tablist" data-value-id="option_188647_7a6a36de-cae4-426e-848e-9770e831ab53" class="button-value-div">

     <button role="tab" type="button" data-value-id="value_188647_7a6a36de-cae4-426e-848e-9770e831ab53_9

3ffc302-3c0a-4c2b-885f-8e893241802c" id="black" class="beside-image test-sin" data-default="1">

        </button>
           
       <button aria-selected="false" role="tab" type="button" data-value-id="value_188647_7a6a36de-cae4-426e-848e-9770e831ab53_3fa2c66a-22ce-42df-b978-61eaba10131c" id="white" class="beside-image test-sin">

       </button>

   </div>

  <script>
$(document).ready(function($){
  $("button").attr("data-selected","false");
  $("button").addClass("test");

  $('.test').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') == "false") {  // Change is here.
      $(this).attr("data-selected","false");
    } 
    else {
      $(this).attr("data-selected", "false");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `event.preventDefault();` on the callback, capturing the `event`?